# The relationship between degree of vertex and size of dominating set

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, co.combinatorics, randomized-algorithms

I was wondering is there any relationship between degree of vertex and size of dominating set. For example, if I know the number of vertices is $n$, and I could know each vertex in the graph has degree $\ge n^k \,(k< 1)$, is it possible to bound the size of dominating set, i.e $O(n^k)$? Could anyone point me out any materials/papers/books related to this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all vertices have degree at least $d$ then there is always a dominating set of size $\frac{n \ln n}{d} + 1$. Pick a random set $S$ of size $\frac{n \ln n}{d}$. For a particular vertex $v$, the probability that $v$ is not dominated by $S$ is upper bounded by $(1 - \frac{d}{n})^{\frac{n\ln n}{d}} \leq e^{-\ln n} = \frac{1}{n}$. Introduce an indicator variable for every vertex that is $1$ if it is not dominated by $S$ and $0$ otherwise. The number of undominated vertices is the sum of indicator variables, so the expected number of undominated vertices is at most $n \cdot \frac{1}{n} = 1$. Hence there exists a set of size $\frac{n \ln n}{d}$ that leaves at most one vertex undominated, add this vertex to the dominating set.

For your question it means that if all vertices have degree at least $n^k$ then there is a dominating set of size $n^{1-k}\log n + 1$. Would be nice to see if one can get rid of the $\log n$ or not.

Comment: How do you get that probability bound? ​ ​

Comment: Imagine picking S in $n \ln n/d$ rounds adding one vertex to S at a time. The probability that $v$ becomes dominated in round $i$ is at least $d/n$ since it has at least $d$ neighbors and we pick from $n-i+1 \geq n$ vertices. So the probability that $v$ never gets dominated is at most $(1-(d/n))$ to the power of the number of rounds.

Comment: Ah, yes. ​ However, it seems like `\frac{n \ln n}{d}` should be replaced with `\left\lceil \hspace{-0.04 in}\frac{n\cdot (\hspace{.02 in}\ln n)}d\hspace{-0.04 in}\right\rceil`. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that the log n factor can be removed? I suspect that it may be necessary.

Comment: Another way to see the bound is by observing that if you can obtain a fractional solution to the dominating set by setting a value of $1/(d+1)$ on each vertex where $d$ is the minimum degree. The total value of this fractional solution is $n/(d+1)$ and it is easy to see that it is feasible. Now by randomized rounding or known integrality gap results there is an integral solution of value $n\ln n/(d+1)$.

Comment: Isn't the integrality gap $\log d$? Then one could excgange the $\log n$ factor with $\log d$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The bound should be $n H_{d+1}/(d+1)$ where $H_k$ is the $k$'th harmonic number. $H_{d+1}$ is at most $1 + \ln (d+1)$. Hence this bound matches what Florent posted in the answer below.

Comment: I believe the right asymptotic bound also falls out if you pick each vertex for a dominating set with probability $\Theta(\log d / (d+1))$ and apply the local lemma.

Answer (score 5):

**1)** To refine daniello's answer, there is a standard bound in domination that for any graph of minimum degree $d$, there is a dominating set of size at most (roughly) $\frac{\log d}{d}n$.
This bound has a simple and nice probabilistic proof (similar to the one given by daniello); see for example Theorem 1.2.2 in the Alon-Spencer book *The probabilistic method* (there the exact bound they give is $\frac{1+\ln (d+1)}{d+1}n$).

Moreover the bound is known to be asymptotically tight. See [this paper by Alon](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01787474), also available on the author's webpage, for the tightness (in the language of hypergraph transversals).

Note that for small values of $d$, it is an active field of research to determine the best bound, and the situation is not yet fully understood already for small $d$; see [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00373-015-1585-7) for a nice discussion about this, as well as some early references for the above bound.

Now, when $d=n^k$, the bound gives a dominating set of size roughly $kn^{1-k}\ln n$, about the same as what we get from daniello's answer. I don't know whether the Alon construction is tight for such values of $d$, but my guess would be yes.

**2)** A second easy observation is that when the degrees are bounded by above (say by $\Delta$), any vertex can dominate at most $\Delta+1$ vertices and hence any dominating set has size at least $\frac{n}{\Delta+1}$. This is easily seen to be tight by creating a graph from a collection of disjoint stars with $\Delta$ leaves each (potentially adding a few edges to make it connected).

Comment: Thank you @Florent Foucaud, especially for the referenced paper you provided.